# Facebook API sometimes doesn't load

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having problem when using

```
 $facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

When loading the page for the first time, nothing happen. I have to reload the page again to make the script work. Not sure where the problem is.

```
require_once('src/facebook.php');

$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";

// Init facebook api.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'publish_stream, user_likes'
        )
);

if (!$user_id) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}

$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
$user_gender = $user_profile['gender'];
    if($user_gender == 'male'){
        echo "you are male";
    } else {
        if ($user_gender == 'female'){
            echo "you are female";
        } else{
            echo "gender not specified";
        }
    }
```

I tried take the  $facebook->api('/me','GET');  out and echo $user_id, for example, it works.

Comment: Ensure the callback/redirect url listed in the $loginUrl correctly points to your php page.